# Can a line in a file in the /etc/sudoers.d directory have multiple users?

Tags: permissions, redhat, sudo, user-permissions

I've got the following file setting permissions on my machine:

```
/etc/sudoers.d/myuser
```

This has the following contents:

```
myuser ALL=(myuser) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I'd like to add a second user to this list, something like:

```
myuser ALL=(myuser, myuser2) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

My question is: **Can a line in a file in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory have multiple users?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, according to [`man sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html) this is allowed.

However, the way you have it it might not work the way you intend to. The part in the parentheses is the user(s), which are allowed to be impersonated via sudo.

Your existing line allows the user `myuser` to run commands as `myuser` without using a password, which doesn't make much sense (he can run commands as himself without sudo anyway).

Your modified line allows the user `myuser` to run commands as himself, or as the user `myuser2`. If this is what you want, fine.

If you want both `myuser` and `myuser2` to run commands as `myuser`, you have to add `myuser2` at the beginning:

```
myuser, myuser2 ALL=(myuser) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you want to allow these two users to run administrative commands it should be:

```
myuser, myuser2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can

Effectively the include  files from `/etc/sudoers.d/` get merged into the main /etc/sudoers configuration file so any directive and combination of directives valid in the main file can be used in the include files